# How to to make /Home/Index redirect to /

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Given the default route, either of the following URLs will navigate to the `Index` method of the `Home` controller:

```
 1. http://localhost
 2. http://localhost/Home/Index
```

I want to make it so that when the user navigates to `localhost/Home/Index` they will be redirected to `localhost` *or* presented with a not found result. 
`

**My aim is to disable the `Home/Index` address without removing the default route (as it is useful in other places.**

I want achieve this because I have some hard-coded relative URLs in my JS that only work when they are relative to `localhost`.

The default route by the way, looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route file, add this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         name: "HomeRedirect",
         url: "Home/Index",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", redirect = true }
 );
```

In your HomeController

```
   public ActionResult Index(bool? redirect)
    {
        if (redirect.HasValue && redirect.Value)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", new { redirect = null as object });
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: this does not disable the `/Home/Index`. request will still hit the `index` action of `home` controller. OP wants to prevent the request from hitting the `index` at `home`. same with @Brunis's answer.

Comment: @Zafarbek His statement above says "I want to make it so that when the user navigates to localhost/Home/Index they will be redirected to localhost". This is exactly what I did. This also does not remove the default route.

Comment: he is going to use `Home/Index` in other places. how he does this in your case?

Comment: @Zafarbek He can still access the `Home/Index` by going to `/` of his webpage.

Answer (score -1):

In your Index() method of your HomeController you just add a:

```
Redirect("~/");
```